# Is it possible to include in-line math in a header?

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I want to do the following:

```
---
title: "My Title"
format: pdf
editor: visual
---

## Find the median $m$ and first and third quartiles for the random variable $X$ having

#### a) The exponential distribution with pdf $f(x) = \lambda e − \lambda x$.

#### b) The Pareto distribution with parameter $\alpha > 0$ with pdf $f(x) = \alpha/x^{\alpha+1}$ for $x \geq 1$
```

But it doesn't display the in-line math correctly (e.g. it displays "\lambda" instead of "", and also displays the "$" symbols), even after rendering it. Is this possible?

## Edit:

Apparently is just a bug, by adding a second "$" sign after the first one it started working, then I just deleted the first one and now is displaying correctly.

Comment: This works for me, try adding `latex_engine: xelatex` after `format: pdf`